# Python: Creating a class from a baseclass inside another class created from a baseclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, nested

In the following, B is an outer class, which inherits from Bbase, and A is an inner class, which inherits from Abase.

I create B with class variable B.b=None, then alter B.b. I then repeat the process. In the new derived class, I find that indeed B.b=None, so I have created a pristine replicate of the B class, which was my intent. So far, so good.

Also within B, I create a class A with class variable A.a=None, and I alter that as well.

However, in the repetition of the process, what I thought was my new replicate of A turns out to have A.a equal to the previously altered value, rather than None which I expect from the initializer in the base class. That is, I have not received a pristine replicate of A after all, but rather my replicate of B contains the same class A (or perhaps a copy with the same alteration) that I created earlier. This is shown by the following code and output.

I actually want my otherwise pristine replicate of B to contain a pristine replicate of A, rather than the previously modified version of A. How can I accomplish this?

Code:

```
class Abase():
    a = None

class Bbase():
    b = None
    class A(Abase): pass

print('Run 1')
class B(Bbase): pass
print('B.b, B.A.a=', B.b, B.A.a, '(Expect "None None")')
B.b = 23
B.A.a = 47
print('B.b, B.A.a=', B.b, B.A.a, '(Expect "23 47")')
print()

print('Run 2')
class B(Bbase): pass
print('B.b, B.A.a=', B.b, B.A.a, '(Expect "None None")')
B.b = 23
B.A.a = 47
print('B.b, B.A.a=', B.b, B.A.a, '(Expect "23 47")')
```

Output (Python 3.7.0, MacOS 10.13.6):

```
Run 1
B.b, B.A.a= None None (Expect "None None")
B.b, B.A.a= 23 47 (Expect "23 47")

Run 2
B.b, B.A.a= None 47 (Expect "None None") <====
B.b, B.A.a= 23 47 (Expect "23 47")
```

By the way, if I create A outside of B, then insert it into B via `B.A = A`, this has the desired effect. I was hoping, though, to create it within B, like the other objects belonging to class B.

## Resolution

First, as a result of this discussion and a followup with colleagues at [Hack Manhattan](http://hackmanhattan.com), I've been disapprised of a serious misconception about how inheritance works in Python. I had thought that an invocation like `class Bbase(): pass; class B(Bbase): pass` created a new class B and then, conceptually, executed the code from Bbase in B. But in fact, conceptually, it just copies the objects into B that were created when Bbase was created. That was my Aha! moment. Perhaps someone else will find this useful. *(Note that the last explanation is wrong, too. See discussion with user2357112 below.)*

Second, the following works well:

```
class Abase():
    a = None

class Bbase():
    b = None
    @classmethod
    def getA(cls):
        class A(Abase): pass
        cls.A = A
```

Then, I can repeat an invocation like `class B(Bbase): pass; B.getA()` as many times as I'd like, and each time I will get a pristine B containing a pristine A. It's sort of a monkey patch, keeping the monkey in the cage.

Comment: You set `B.A.a` to `47`  Why would you expect it to later be `None`?

Comment: `B.A` is created when the module is imported.  IE, only once.

Comment: It seems odd (well, unintuitive) to me that the invocation of 'class A(Abase)` inside the newly created class B actually does not create a new class, but it seems to me that that is what you are saying. Can you think of a way to actually create a new class A inside my replicate of class B, or, as far as you know, am I stuck with the workaround I referred to in my last sentence?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is instances. You generally only want to define `class B` _once_. If you want multiple `B` with different `A`'s, you want to attach that to a `B` instance, not the class itself.

Comment: "I had thought that an invocation like class Bbase(): pass; class B(Bbase): pass created a new class B and then, conceptually, executed the code from Bbase in B. But in fact, conceptually, it just copies the objects into B that were created when Bbase was created" - no, neither of those things. It doesn't reexecute the base class body, and it doesn't copy anything. `Bbase` just goes in `B`'s MRO, the series of classes attribute lookup goes through when it doesn't find an attribute on `B` itself.

Comment: @user2357112 strengthens my argument. What you're doing is declaring / defining classes, you're not executing any code before you invoke an actual method. `class B(Bbase)` in the end will only create a classs called `B` that contains a reference to `Bbase` as super class.

Comment: @Nearoo These examples do not illustrate the purpose of creating several classes in this manner, just the problem that I'm encountering in doing so. Your response makes sense for my simple example, but not for the actual use case. Having said that, there might have been better design choices, but the one you are proposing would certainly not map onto my use case.

Comment: @user2357112 It is more complicated than that. Consider the following:

class Abase():
    a = None
class A(Abase): pass
class AA(Abase): pass
A.a = 23
print(A.a, AA.a)

Your explanation would predict that AA.a should be 23, because you seem to be saying that there is a single 'a' residing in Abase that the last assignment above just altered. But in fact, AA.a is still None, as shown by the print statement.

Comment: @wchlm: No multi-line formatting in comments. Even if you get a line break into the comment box, it won't be a line break in the resulting comment. You can't write complicated code snippets in a comment. Try ideone or pastebin or something.

Comment: @wchlm: Assigning to `A.a` doesn't care whether an `a` attribute already exists and doesn't look through the MRO. Attribute assignment doesn't go through the fallbacks attribute retrieval goes through unless you write a descriptor or a `__setattr__` telling it to do so manually. The `A.a` assignment assigns on `A` itself.

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://ideone.com/50AC1f) showing that the "copy" theory is wrong. After *explicitly deleting* a subclass attribute, attribute retrieval still finds the value in the parent class. Also, reassigning the superclass attribute value is reflected in the subclass, despite the reassignment happening after the creation of the subclass.

Comment: You say that nearo's suggestion won't map onto your use-case, but I highly doubt that. Indeed, classes *are instances* of the class `type`. You can even create a class using the `type` constructor: `MyClass = type('MyClass', (), {})`

Comment: @user2357112 It seems to me that if things were not "more complicated" than your earlier statement, then, in your ideone, line 5 would have altered A.a as well as B.a. But it does not. At that point A and B have different a's.

Yes, the "copy" theory is wrong. But it's more complicated than the picture of there being one true 'a' shared by everybody, which is the way I read your remark. 

Would you agree with the assertion that when an assignment is made to an inherited variable in B, a new variable of the same name is created that hides the one in the superclass? If not, then what?

Comment: @wchlm: That's accurate.

Comment: @@user2357112 It sounds a little like "copy-on-write" in OS memory management. :-) Thanks much for your help and the time you put into explaining it.